# How to create a listbox in HTML without allowing multiple selection?

Tags: html, listbox

I don't have much experience in HTML. I am looking to create a simple listbox, but one of the requirements is to DISALLOW multiple selection. Most of the code for listboxes goes like this -

```
 <select name="sometext" multiple="multiple">
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
    <option>text4</option>
    <option>text5</option>
 </select>
```

But this allows for multiple selection.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900019/select-element-in-the-multiple-selection-display-style-without-allowing-multiple), a similar question was asked, but the "best" answer has been downvoted. So I am not sure how else this could be done. Please help.

Comment: For you other newcomers, please avoid the aforementioned website for your own good - they've got good SEO but that's about it. It's riddled with bad practices and habits you'll be sorry you learned later on.  Use the API from MDN (Mozilla), in this case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the warning. His comment "This is why I have a job" came across as arrogant too. If you have a job, good for you. This is a forum for answers and not advertisements.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Just use the size attribute:

```
<select name="sometext" size="5">
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
  <option>text3</option>
  <option>text4</option>
  <option>text5</option>
</select>
```

To clarify, adding the size attribute did not remove the multiple selection.

The single selection works because you removed the multiple="multiple" attribute.

Adding the size="5" attribute is still a good idea, it means that at least 5 lines must be displayed. See the full reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Upvoted for truth. Also, when the question was posted previously, this solution may not have been as widely supported by all browsers.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because there isn't anything in the HTML standards that require the browser to render it as a listbox if the size attribute is set. Yes, all major browsers currently do, but there's no guarantee they always will. Realistically though, this would be a breaking change for so many websites, no browser is likely to change it.

Comment: The standard is open to a little interpretation: _"The display size of a select element is the result of applying the rules for parsing non-negative integers to the value of element's **size** attribute, if it has one and parsing it is successful."_ Whilst this does not specifically state that it should be displayed as a Dropdown or Listbox, it would be difficult to display a Dropdown control which shows more than 1 element. (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-select-element)

Comment: Thanks!! And this could be dynamic, obviously, with Js :D

Answer (score 58):

Remove the multiple="multiple" attribute and add SIZE=6 with the number of elements you want

you may want to check this site

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT.html

Answer (score 2):

For Asp.Net MVC

```
@Html.ListBox("parameterName", ViewBag.ParameterValueList as MultiSelectList, 
 new { 
 @class = "chosen-select form-control"
 })
```

or

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.parameterName,
  ViewBag.ParameterValueList as MultiSelectList,
   new{
       data_placeholder = "Select Options ",
       @class = "chosen-select form-control"
   })
```