# HTML Listbox without multiple selection

Tags: html, select, listbox

I want to have a Listbox, that does not allow multiple selections, and has a scrollbar if it has more than three items (I will be using PHP to dynamically update the contents). I saw [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619776/how-to-create-a-listbox-in-html-without-allowing-multiple-selection) but I want it to only be three items high, so that it does not get bigger and bigger.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `size` attribute.

```
<select size="3">
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be a select box with the size attribute set?

```
<select name="select" size="3" id="select">
   <option value="1">Item 1</option>
</select>
```