# GET data from Viewdata of SelectList to HTML.Listbox without multiselect option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am passing selectlist data from controller to view in a viewdata. Now I want to assign that viewdata selectlist to @HTML.Listbox. I want a list of size 4 but user can select only single item at a time. I know code of multi-select but i don't know for single item.

Code for multiselect:
controller:

```
ViewData["ddlList"] = new SelectList(ROIDL.GetDataList(), "List_Val", "List_Text");
```

html:

```
@Html.ListBox("ddlMCL", ViewData["ddlMCL"] as MultiSelectList)
```

Comment: why do not you pass the data by the model? Have you got any restriction with that?

Comment: @RubéndelaFuente Yes. That's why I am getting data into viewdata. and as multiselectlist it is working fine.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619776/how-to-create-a-listbox-in-html-without-allowing-multiple-selection

Comment: @AmarDuplantier, yes of this kind but with the use of html.listbox html helper.

Comment: Do what that post says. Try setting the size attribute of the listbox using the helper.

Comment: Or you can go for @Html.DropdownList since you are going to select only one item.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with something similar to that, you need a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
ViewData["ddlList"] = ROIDL.GetDataList().Select(e => new SelectListItem()
                                        {
                                            Value = e.List_Val,
                                            Text = e.List_Text
                                        }).ToList();


@Html.ListBox("ddlMCL",  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["ddlMCL"])
```

Comment: @Html.ListBox("ddlMCL", ViewData["ddlMCL"]) giving error